# Is spring framework 3.2.13 is compatible with Java 11

Tags: java, spring

I need to upgrade my project to Java 11, so am wondering what is the minimum version of Spring Framework version supported my Java 11.

As of now my project contains Java 8 and spring 3.2.13

I ran my project with Java 11 and Spring 3.2.13, I didn't face any issue.
But I want to make it clear will Java 11 support Spring 3.2.13 is supported , so that in further it should not cause any issue.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from [Spring Project Github Wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#jdk-version-range)

> Please upgrade to Spring Framework 5.1+ (and the corresponding Spring
>   Boot 2.1+) for JDK 11+ support, as the common Long-Term Support
>   migration path from JDK 8. No earlier Spring versions are officially
>   supported on JDK 11, in particular not with JDK 11 bytecode level.
>   Note that third-party components might not fully support JDK 11 yet,
>   so you are likely to be limited in your full-stack options.